# z3 (py) smt-lib2 output

Tags: python, z3, smt

How to output assertions made with z3py in SMT-LIB2 format? I can't find any mention of that in the documentation. I found a flag `Z3_PRINT_SMTLIB_FULL` but I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method sexpr().
For example:
  http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/9t

```
x, y = Reals('x y')
print (x + y * 3).sexpr()
```

There is online documentation of the Python API.
For example, the sexpr() method is documented under:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/z3.html#ExprRef

Comment: Do you want an output that is a valid SMT 2.0 script?

Comment: We will add this feature in a future release. I agree it is very useful.

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura: Was this eventually added?